# File not found in Linux while the file is there

Tags: linux, openwrt

Aim is to run the file sendData.c with passing argument. But it shows file not found while it is already there. Let me know where it is going wrong.

```
root@OpenWrt:/tmp/sendData# ls -l
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            75 Dec 19 07:02 Makefile
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          5627 Dec 18 07:33 sendData.c
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         13162 Dec 18 07:33 send_Data
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         10744 Dec 20 07:46 send_Data_loop
root@OpenWrt:/tmp/sendData# ./sendData wlan0 E8:DE:27:C3:E6:07
-ash: ./sendData: not found
```

Comment: look again carefully

Comment: make should make your executable

Comment: After running make in cross-compiler the sendData.c was generated. Now I have transferred the file in openwrt to run

Answer (score 1):

The file you want to use is called differently

```
# ./send_Data wlan0 E8:DE:27:C3:E6:07
```

I think you have a confusing naming scheme, because your .c file is named without and underscore

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
Did not execute the "make" for which the sendData file was not generated in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, make your file executable:
`chmod +x <filename>` and run command again.

Comment: The result is same

Comment: You sure you are in correct directory and type correct file name?

Comment: Yes, I am in the same directory with correct file name